# include file ruby selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple ruby test cases for selenium-webdriver and all the files are sharing the same functions. is there any way to create a global file and include the file to these test cases instead of typing them over and over again

for example - I create a file setup.rb

```
def setup

    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) 
end
```

then in my test_file.rb I start

```
require setup

 setup
 @driver.find_element(:xpath => '//span[text()="войти"]').click
```

There is an error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to a global variable from an instance variable. Make it `$driver` instead of `@driver` and you shouldn't have a problem. Change it to something like..

```
def self_setup

    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) 
end
```

and then

```
require "./setup.rb"

 setup.setup
 $driver.find_element(:xpath => '//span[text()="войти"]').click
```

That should work. You'd probably want to go to a page first before you look for that xpath though. setup will only open up a new instance of firefox webdriver. Also I would suggest changing the name of setup.rb so it can be `foo.setup` insead of `setup.setup`. I use Lib.rb for the methods I want to be able to call regularly so for instance one would be `Lib.signin_admin`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Have an upvote!  This solved a problem I've been having!  Thanks from 4 years in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

In response to your example, I think you forgot to include the setup module (you did put your method definition inside a module, right?). Also, the comment that mentions assigning the driver as a global variable (by naming it with a starting dollar sign) is a good idea. So things would look like this...

setup.rb

```
module Setup
  def setup
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    $wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) 
  end
end
```

test_file.rb

```
require 'setup'
class SeleniumTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Setup # Modules need to be included (mixed-in) in order to be used inside classes 

  # Setup is automagically called when using TestUnit

  $driver.get "http://www.yoururl.com"
  $driver.find_element(:xpath => '//span[text()="войти"]').click
end
```

The downside is that for each new module and file you create, you have to require and include all of the new files and modules you want to use.

The method that I have found to work for me is to create a 'test_helper.rb', and to use a gem called 'require_all' that requires and includes all of the files from the directories you specify.

My test_helper.rb looks something like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "require_all"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test-unit"

require_all relative_path("../lib/selenium/")

module TestHelpers
  include Selenium

  def setup

    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    ...

  end

  def teardown

    $driver.quit

  end

end
```

And the test_page.rb only requires two lines:

```
# Line 1: Ensures the test_helper.rb gets loaded from the same directory the test_page.rb resides in
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'test_helper') 

class TestPage < Test::Unit::TestCase

  # Line 2: Module needs mixed in to use its methods
  include TestHelpers

  def test_page

    $driver.get "http://www.mysite.com"
    assert $driver.find_element(:css => "div#my_site_logo")

  end

end
```